# Site.Master Changes

Tags: asp.net

I started out with a basic site.master.  After I laid out several pages, I have found that I need to make changes to the site.master.  The changes show up while I am working in Visual Studio, but when I run the application, they don't take effect.  What do I need to do to have them show up?

Comment: Where are you running the application? Did you deploy the changes there?

Comment: I am using the development IIs server that get launched when I use the debugger.

Comment: What changes have you made? Did you clear the browser cache?

Comment: I adjusted the size of the page in the css file, shut down and restarted the development server, but I don't see the page size change.

Comment: The CSS file is probably still cached in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make changes to CSS or javascript (or any other static content, for that matter), you need to clear out the browser cache to ensure the latest version is loaded from your server.

You can force a reload from the server by using <kbd>Ctrl + F5</kbd> on most browsers.